# Hardware FM synthesizer similar to DX-7?

Tags: hardware, synthesis

I'm looking for a FM synthesizer (either keyboard or rack) that is similar to the Yamaha DX-7, but more modern and that would include the following features:

- Musical patches based on modulation synthesis only, NOT on sampled sounds like on the average modern synths
- The ability to program your own modulation synth sound and to modify the pre-programmed ones
- Ideally would be comabitble with General MIDI sounds and drums and with MIDI ports

I found many software solutions, but I'd like something I can use without the need to turn on my PC. Does such an instrument even exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , the new Volca FM, takes up all the DX 7 stuff & sounds:

*the Volca FM is set to be its finest example so far: a three-voice polyphonic FM synthesizer, which is FULLY compatible with the old DX7 sounds, via SysEx, which means you can import old sound libraries from the DX7 into the new Volca.*

Quoted from [here](http://www.dolphinmusic.co.uk/article/5997-korg-volca-fm-other-ways-to-get-the-dx7-sound.html)

Also plenty of info in a fast web crawl about Volca FM.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Korg Kronos will do all you want and import dx7 patches.
You may also look for older synths like the sy77 and sy99 or yamaha synths that will accept an add-on card (plg-150dx) like motif es or S90es as those will also load dx7 sys-ex.